# Calabi-Yau conditions for a threefold in the Grassmannian $Gr(2,7)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology, kahler-manifolds

I am trying to show a complete intersection $X$ in the grassmannian $G(2,7)$ is a Calabi-Yau in the strict sense. By that I mean $\omega_X\cong\mathcal{O}_X$ and $h^i(\mathcal{O}_X)=0$ for $i=1,2$.

The description of $X$ is given by $X=Gr(2,7)\cap{H}^7$ under the Plücker embedding $i:Gr(2,7)\hookrightarrow\mathbb{P}^{20}$ where $H^7$ is a generic intersection of $7$ hyperplanes in $\mathbb{P}^{20}$.

I showed the part $\omega_X\cong\mathcal{O}_X$ by using adjunction formula and the canonical sheaf $\omega_{G(2,7)}$ of the grassmannian $G(2,7)$.

For the second part I think I know $h^1(\mathcal{O}_X)=h^2(\mathcal{O}_X)$ by Serre duality.

How can I show $h^1(\mathcal{O}_X)=0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As $X$ is a complete intersection, it follows from the Lefschetz Hyperplane Theorem that $\pi_1(X) \cong \pi_1(\operatorname{Gr}(2, 7)) = 0$, so $H^1(X; \mathbb{C}) = 0$. Since $X$ is Kähler, we have $H^1(X; \mathbb{C}) \cong H^{1,0}_{\bar{\partial}}(X)\oplus H^{0,1}_{\bar{\partial}}(X)$ and hence $H^{0,1}_{\bar{\partial}}(X) = 0$. Finally, by Dolbeault's theorem, we see that $H^1(X, \mathcal{O}_X) \cong H^{0,1}_{\bar{\partial}}(X) = 0$.

Comment: (Your first assertion follows from Lefschetz, I presume.)

Comment: Can you give a reference for the isomorphism and the latter cohomology being 0?

Comment: I have added some explanation. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Yes, I should have mentioned this.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Thank you for the answer. That's quite helpful, at least I learned Dolbeault's theorem. I would be happy if I see some answer using exact sequences and etc. as well.

Comment: I'm confused about the $\pi_1$ statement. I'm pretty sure that in $Gr(2,5)$ a generic intersection of 5 hyperplanes is an elliptic curve, so, $\pi_1\neq 1$. What's different in the two situations?

Comment: @AllenKnutson: Note that $\operatorname{Gr}(2, 5)$ is six-dimensional, so the complete intersection you describe is one-dimensional. On the other hand, $\operatorname{Gr}(2, 7)$ is ten-dimensional, so the complete intersection the OP described is three-dimensional. For a smooth complete intersection $Y$ in $\mathbb{CP}^N$ of dimension $m$, we have $\pi_i(Y) \cong \pi_i(\mathbb{CP}^N)$ for $0 \leq i \leq m-1$; see Corollary I.20.5 of *Compact Complex Surfaces* by Barth, Hulek, Peters, and Van de Ven for example.

Comment: @AllenKnutson: Could you loose some words on the idea how to see that a generic intersection of $5$ hyperplanes (ie pullbacks of hyperplanes along Pluecker map) in $Gr(2,5)$ is an elliptic curve?

Comment: The anticanonical class on $Gr(k,n)$ is $\mathcal O(n)$. As we pass to the 1-,2-,...5-fold intersection of these divisors, we can compute their anticanonical classes each step using the adjunction formula. When we're done we have a 1-d variety (smooth and irreducible by Bertini) whose anticanonical class is zero. Hence, an elliptic curve.